# Spring mvc How to bind request parameter to Controller attribute , like struts2

Tags: java, spring, web, struts2

In Spring MVC, it is easy to bind request parameter to method paramaters handling the request. I just use @RequestParam

```
@Controller
public class ConfirmOrderAction {
       public String toConfirmOrder(@RequestParam String itemIds){
       } 
}
```

but  i hope like this

```
@Controller
public class ConfirmOrderAction {
       @RequestParam
       private String itemIds;
       getItemIds(){}
       setItemIds(){}
       public String toConfirmOrder(){} 
}
```

like struts2

Comment: Why you Need this way?

Comment: This project was struts2
Now we want to change the spring mvc

Comment: Wait... you have a Struts2 project and you're changing it to spring mvc? but... but... Why? ;(

Comment: this is my boss idea

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Spring's `@RequestParam` annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RequestParam {
 ...
}
```

This means `@RequestParam` can only be used on method parameters.

Do not forget that Spring controllers are singletons by default (one instance is shared by multiple requests). So it would be a bad idea to bind request parameters to instance fields.

Comment: thanks ,singletons problem can i use scope="prototype" to slove it ?
i hope bind request parameter to  Controller attribute,  not use @RequestParam annotion  or  other annotation

Comment: Yes prototype scope would change this. However, I would recommend to avoid state inside controllers.